# How to return http status code 409 (conflict) along with JSON response from spring REST API, when duplicate email is used during user registration?

Tags: json, spring, rest, model-view-controller, conflict

So far I have tried the following solutions, 
1. Using Response object, but I don't wish to use servlet API of JSP.
2. I tried the folliwing solution which gives html response with status code but I want it to be JSON instead of html, here is the relevant code snippet. 
Fetching the user with email supplied from the UI

```
final User user = userDao.findByEmail(email);
if (user != null) {
throw new DuplicateRequestException();
}
```

Here is my exception class:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CONFLICT,
reason = "email already in use")
public class DuplicateRequestException extends RuntimeException {
}
```

I am using a @RestController in my spring MVC application, I am getting the desired status code and message but the response is in HTML format, how can I get JSON response with the status code instead? Thanks.

Comment: If you're using tomcat, it sometimes overrides what should be a json response if `javax.servlet.error.exception` is set on the request. I have encountered this using `@ControllerAdvice` and `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`, in which case the attribute can either be removed or skipped by not calling some of the `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` methods.

Comment: Yes I am using tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

What about `ResponseEntity` class?

```
final User user = userDao.findByEmail(email);
if (user != null) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(someJsonObject, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
}
```

Don't forget annotation `@ResponseBody` for this method.